# sdkmanager: command not found

Tags: java, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I have use this link https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/install-android-sdk-manager-linux-ubuntu-16-04/ for install sdk manager and it work fine as an ubuntu user , but when trying to do same steps as root then try to check it by type (sdkmanager --list) it return "sdkmanager: command not found"
what would be the problem?
how to install android-sdk as root ? and how to check if installed ?
.. help please thanks

Comment: have you found out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I've found and it may probably help someone in the future.  Try to install the SDK Manager snap if you're using Linux: https://snapcraft.io/install/androidsdk/mint. Then instead of using `sdkmanager --list` , use `androidsdk  --list`.

This means that you will use `androidsdk` command instead of `sdkmanager` to make installations.